# Can I connect GPS module (NEO-6m) to bluetooth module HC-05 directly?

Tags: uart, bluetooth, gps

Since I have poor GPS reception in my car I thought I could forward GPS data from GPS module to a phone via bluetooth.

I am using NEO-6M GPS module and HC-05 bluetooth module.

At first I was thinking about using Arduino, but then it occured to me that both GPS and bluetooth modules are operating 3.3V UARTs on respective inputs and outputs. Therefore is there any downside in connecting their TX and RX lines directly? By default both modules use 9600 baudrate so I don't think any configuration is needed.

Comment: I don't know what the HC-05 does. If it just transparently handle the RX and TX lines, well, that could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The HC-05 is meant to be a drop in module for TTL level serial connections. Simply cross connect the TX and RX lines (if you are certain both use 3.3V levels), power and ground, connect to the bluetooth device and you are good to go. As a serial port.

As for actually using it as a NMEA GPS in android, that may not be so easy. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139047/how-to-extract-nmea-outputs-from-an-external-bluetooth-gps-to-an-android-device and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155848/handling-data-from-external-bluetooth-device-with-gps-nmea-strings

Answer (score 1):

UART usually works in two voltage levels. In simple terms, 3.3V and 5V. You will need to find voltage level of the UART used in your GPS device and then match it with the Bluetooth module. If you are unable to do this, you can use level converter. These can be easily purchased through eBay. The most important thins is to know the voltage levels you are operating so you wont burn your GPS.